# I need some new blogs to help learn my new language (it's C)

Tags: c, linux, reference, gtk, blogs

I'm a **BIG** blog reader. I can't stop reading blogs. Blogs helped me find this site (in particular [Jeff's blog](http://www.codinghorror.com/)). However I've come to realize that all the blogs I read deal with one language.

- [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/)
- [Fabulous Adventures In Coding](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/default.aspx)
- [Jon Skeet's Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/)
- [Scott Hanselman's Blog](http://hanselman.com/)

Did you guess the language?

Well now I'm learning C and using GTK (The [Gimp Tool Kit](http://www.gtk.org/)). I can't really find any bloggers who actually blog about C like [Jeff](http://www.codinghorror.com/), [Eric](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/default.aspx), [Jon](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/), or [Scott](http://hanselman.com/) do about C#. I need the blogger to be active, and it'll help if he has a sense of humor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to keep an eye on this fellow named "Jibz" who recently started up:
http://www.hardtoc.com/

Comment: Looks like it's going to be an excellent blog. It's written by Jørgen Ibsen of http://www.ibsensoftware.com/.

Comment: OMG, an up-to-date blog about C! I didn't think they existed anymore.

Comment: Turns out your the only one to list a C blog.

Answer (score 6):

I think that the C equivalent of a blog is called a book. Step away from the internet browser :-)

Comment: But...But...That means not being on my computer! I really find it harder to read books. I can't seem to search (Ctrl-F) them as fast. ;-)

Comment: I think that crosses the mind of every computer-person when reading books!

Answer (score 5):

I go back to the 90s with C.  I'll write more if people will read.

That thing about books was explained to by a friend (jacox): "You can't grep a dead tree."

Comment: I upvoted, so start writing more blog post! ;-)

Comment: I'm super-interested in a C blog... so get posting.

Answer (score 2):

I'm really sorry, but I've made the same search, and the result of my search was sad but expected. C# is a hot topic these days in development circles compared to C [*].

**I'd love to be proven wrong,** but there is simply nothing in the C world equivalent to the blogs you've mentioned.

[*] I am not criticizing C, It has been my bread and butter for the last 3.5 years, just stating the reality

Comment: I hear you man. It sucks because I think it would be a great way to learn C. I'm wanting to help contribute to GEdit and some other open source stuff.

Answer (score 2):

C is not as *hip* as C# and friends. You will not find many blogs about it.

The only blog I can think of where I got some relevant C info is, [There Is NO Box](http://tinobox.com/wordpress/).

Comment: Well that's one more then I found. Thanks.

Comment: yeah, check out his object-oriented C article, interesting stuff.

Comment: OO C? That sounds cool. Almost as cool as Objective-C (sorry I'm an apple fan boy). ;-)

Comment: sure it's hip, it's just not big in this newfangled "blogosphere".  Gotta get to the *real* internet, the web .5 beta 3 stuff, the newsgroups!

Comment: @Yoooder: blogs == hip, newsgroups == not hip